AjaxFileUpload reset select file path
I have VS2019 using asp.net c#
Iwant to know if there is a manner to have a preset path when i push the button "select file"
ie c:\ in manner that the user chooses always the path in his  computer?
i want that when i push the "select File" button the user start from a predefinited path like c:\ ...
therefore if I press "select File" button everytime my application resets client directory path
best regards

No, you can't set the file, path or anything of that nature.
The reason of course is security. If you come to my site to view some cute cat pictures, I can't have browser code THEN select folders, or files, and then say upload files called "my banking" or "my passwords".
So, the selection of a file is 100% controlled by the browser, and not the web server settings, and in fact not even the client side JavaScript settings. And worse yet, is the user might be on a iPad, or even a Android Phone, both of which don't have drive letters anyway.
And keep in mind that upon uploading files, the original (client side) path name is NEVER exposed and provided to the web server, but only the file name.
